# Entity Framework Join Three Entity Sum

Tags: entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-core

I have three entities like following:

```
 public class StockSymbol
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public double Price { get; set; }
        public double PreviousPrice { get; set; }
        public double YesterdayPrice { get; set; }
        public double Change { get; set; }
    }

    public class CustomerOrder
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int StockSymbolId { get; set; }
        public int CustomerId { get; set; }
        public int StockCount { get; set; }
        public DateTime OrderDate { get; set; }

        public Customer Customer { get; set; }
        public StockSymbol Stock { get; set; }
    }

    public class Customer
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Surname { get; set; }
        public double Balance { get; set; }

        public List<CustomerOrder> Orders { get; set; }
    }
```

As you can see, each customer can have multiple stock order and each stock have its own price. I want to calculate the total stock price per each customer. How can I do that with linq or EF? I want to get total order of price per customer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dbContext.Customers
    .Select(c => new
        {
            Customer = c,
            TotalCost = c.Orders.Sum(co => co.StockCount * co.Stock.Price),
        });
```